# Docker push image to Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have modified, added some extra applications to a running container, now I would like to push it to Docker Hub.
I have tagged my image like this:
`docker tag hellodocker:mytag <myuser>/hellodocker:mytag`
Pushing process was succesful, but after pull and run I see, that it contains only the base image, that I have used up, so intalled applications haven't "commited".

Comment: how to run the push command?

Comment: You have to create account at docker-hub and execute command from your command line `docker login`. Then after login - you could execute command `docker push IMAGE`. More information at [docker repos](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockerrepos/)

Comment: @Yuri: I have already logged in to Docker Hub account.

Comment: @KovacsAkos You've mentioned that *Pushing process was succesful, but after pull and run I see, that it contains only the base image, that I have used up, so intalled applications haven't "commited".* What you've forgotten to do is `commit`. Please see the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you haven't done commit of your container. In order to do this - you have to execute the following command:

`docker commit CONTAINER_ID CONTAINER_NAME`

more on this: [Docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/)

**OR**

You could simply execute `docker` command and see its output:

```
...
commit    Create a new image from a container's changes
...
```

Answer (score 10):

1) First login by typing `sudo docker login` in the terminal. Enter username and password

2) Visit your docker account and create a new repository. In my case I created a repository **zawad1879/dockerhub**

3)Say you have a docker image with repository name:**zawad/django** and tag:**latest**.

In that case you will need to tag this image with a label of your wish. I decided to tag it with the label:**myfirstimagepush**. You tag the image by typing the command

```
sudo docker tag zawad/django:latest zawad1879/dockerhub:firstimagepush
```

4) Finally push the image to your repo using the command

```
sudo docker push zawad1879/dockerhub:firstimagepush
```

That's all there is to it.